# Twilio uses the old url

Tags: twilio

I've recently changed /voice url on my twilio's number.

I've changed from a https://domain.localtunnel.me to to http://newdomainname.com.

But, when I'm trying to call someone, twilio still uses the old https url, so I've got many 11200- HTTP retrieval failure errors in my debugger.

Why twilio doesn't use the new url ? My client side doesn't send twilio any kind of URL, so I'm expecting it to use the one I've set on my number page.

Is there a setting I've missed ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430800/how-to-configure-call-url-in-twilio-api

Comment: If you are sure you have definitely updated the number, as in in the instructions in Françios's comment above, then please send me your Account SID to philnash@twilio.com and I'll see if I can see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutly certain it is updated [proof](http://imgur.com/MJGSfHy). I even do seen the modification in the events log for this number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After some more investigation it turned out that the test calls to the number were being made with [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client). When you use Twilio Client you need to provide a TwiML Application which has a URL for what to do when making outbound Twilio calls. In this case, the outbound URL in the TwiML application needed to be updated from the localtunnel version to the new URL too.